# Implement "like" HashMap in js with <string, object>

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I develop an app with react and node js.
I have a JSON file that stores all user objects with some properties (first name, last name, email, ... )

I want to implement "like" hashmap with key, value.
the key is a string for the email and value will be all the user object

like (in java):
HashMap< string, User >

I want this to access fast for a user object, search by email (the key) on server-side (NodeJS)

What is a good way to implement something like this?

Thanks!

Comment: Use Object(`{}`). It is fast as much as HashMap and can be used as HashMap.

Answer (score 1):

What about a simple object in Javascript? 
All objects in Javascript can be accessed by the Array-like convention.
For example, you can create an object like this:

```
const Users = {}
Users['admin@admin.com']=userObject;
Users['test@test.com']=user2Object;
```

ect..

Comment: how can I convert an User array User[] to something like that? i.e. make UsersByEmail = {}, and then how to iterate over the original User[] array?

Comment: Sounds like you need to go through some basic javascript tutorial. Take a look here for example:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Comment: @OriBentov you should iterate with for(let user in Users) loop for example, or you can iterate the keyss with Object.keys(Users).forEach()...

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to work with modern browser/node versions, consider using a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Example from the link above:

```js
let myMap = new Map()

let keyString = 'a string'
let keyObj    = {}
let keyFunc   = function() {}

// setting the values
myMap.set(keyString, "value associated with 'a string'")
myMap.set(keyObj, 'value associated with keyObj')
myMap.set(keyFunc, 'value associated with keyFunc')

myMap.size              // 3

// getting the values
myMap.get(keyString)    // "value associated with 'a string'"
myMap.get(keyObj)       // "value associated with keyObj"
myMap.get(keyFunc)      // "value associated with keyFunc"

myMap.get('a string')    // "value associated with 'a string'"
                         // because keyString === 'a string'
myMap.get({})            // undefined, because keyObj !== {}
myMap.get(function() {}) // undefined, because keyFunc !== function () {}
```